# Search Function is Hang with 2 year data and join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here us the query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE complete='Y'
  AND shipped='Y'
  AND active='Y'
  AND create_dttm > '2013-10-10 08:28:41'
  AND order_id IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT t1.order_id
     FROM Table2 t1
     INNER JOIN table3 t2 ON t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
     WHERE t2.prod_sku LIKE '%D-600%'
       AND t1.create_dttm > '2013-02-15 08:28:41')
```

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag the question appropriately

Comment: And the question was?

Comment: MySql server with php

Comment: When i use 
WHERE t2.prod_sku LIKE '%D-600%'
and data year create_dttm > '2012-10-10 08:28:41'

its Hang the database and site as well

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **sub-query in WHERE clause**, that could be the main reason behind slow execution of your query. Try using JOINS instead of sub query.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON T1.order_id = T2.order_id  
                        AND t2.create_dttm > '2013-02-15 08:28:41'
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.prod_id = t3.prod_id 
                         AND  t3.prod_sku LIKE '%D-600%'          
WHERE complete='Y'
  AND shipped='Y'
  AND active='Y'
  AND create_dttm > '2013-10-10 08:28:41'
```

And also check for indexes on your tables.